# Matrix of boundary distance between countries

Tags: curated-data, geography, geodesy

I'm trying to generate a matrix of the boundary distances between all countries.

First thing I tried was `GeoDistance`:

```
table = ParallelTable[
   QuantityMagnitude@
    GeoDistance[x, y, DistanceFunction -> "Boundary", 
     UnitSystem -> "Metric"],
   {x, countries},
   {y, countries}
   ];
```

But this is way too slow. I tried preloading the `CountryData` paclet, but it didn't make any difference. `GeoDistance` is calling Wolfram's servers for each and every pair of countries.

```
CountryData[All, "Preload"]
RebuildPacletData[]
```

I also tried using `GeoPosition` with `CountryData[COUNTRY, "Coordinates"]`, but I can't figure out how to make this work with `GeoDistance` for `"Boundary"` distance.

Additionally I've looked at geographic questions here, but I haven't found any that is similar enough to mine to give me directions on this.

Is there a way I can do this computation offline and fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a sketch, where I considered only two countries and only one boundary curve description for each of them. Generalization for multiple boundaries at the end.

```
slv = CountryData["El Salvador", "Coordinates"][[1]];
arg = CountryData["Argentina", "Coordinates"][[2]];
slvInt = Interpolation /@ Transpose@slv
argInt = Interpolation /@ Transpose@arg
sol=Timing@Quiet@
    NMinimize[{GeoDistance @@ Through /@ {argInt[r], slvInt[s]}, 
               1 <= s <= 161 && 1 <= r <= 955}, {r, s}, 
               Method -> #] & /@ {Automatic, "SimulatedAnnealing", 
                                  "DifferentialEvolution", "NelderMead", "RandomSearch"}
```

Timings and results on a **very** slow machine:

```
{{53.609375, {4.53166*10^6, {r -> 930.,s -> 106.882}}}, 
 {12.359375, {4.56584*10^6, {r -> 930.472,s -> 120.92}}}, 
 {54.937500, {4.53166*10^6, {r -> 930., s -> 106.882}}}, 
 {12.218750, {4.53401*10^6, {r -> 930., s -> 106.159}}}, 
 {16.968750, {4.56692*10^6, {r -> 930., s -> 128.242}}}}
```

Testing:

```
Graphics[{Gray, EdgeForm[Black], 
  CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ CountryData["SouthAmerica"], 
  CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ CountryData["NorthAmerica"], Thick, 
  Red, Line[ Reverse /@ Through /@ {argInt[r], slvInt[s]} /. sol[[1, 2, 2]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Generalization for multiple boundaries**

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
ifd[x_] := InterpolatingFunctionDomain[x][[1, 2]];
gtb = CountryData["GreatBritain", "Coordinates"];
ice = CountryData["Iceland", "Coordinates"];
borders = Map[Interpolation /@ (Transpose@#) &, #] & /@ {gtb, ice};
tb = Tuples[borders];

sol = (First@
   Sort[MapIndexed[{Quiet@
          NMinimize[{GeoDistance @@ Through /@ {#[[1]][r], #[[2]][s]},
             1 <= s <= ifd[#[[2, 1]]] && 
             1 <= r <= ifd[#[[1, 1]]]}, {r, s}, 
           Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"] &@#1, #2} &, tb]])

{{distance, rule}, {idx}} = sol

Graphics[{Gray, EdgeForm[Black], 
  CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ CountryData["Europe"], Thick, Red, 
  Line[Reverse /@ Through /@ {tb[[idx,1]][r], tb[[idx,2]][s]} /. rule]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is actually along the lines of what I wanted to do (but didn't know how). Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the results: http://bit.ly/1MsRnDE. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Ignore last comment. Turns out all I had to do was to add `QuantityMagnitude` to the `NMinimize` to turn the results from miles into just numbers. One last thing: What did you mean by "only one boundary curve description for each of them"?

Comment: @ivanmp Each separate territory in a country (for example an island) gives you a polygon in `CountryData["xxx", "Coordinates"]`. In my example I considered only one polygon for each country to abbreviate the list mapping coding and make the idea easier  to follow

Comment: Got it. I've generalized it now. Your solution is very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

fast approximation..

```
  slv = Flatten[CountryData["El Salvador", "Coordinates"],1];
  arg = Flatten[CountryData["Argentina", "Coordinates"],1];
  (f = Nearest[slv];
      Min[GeoDistance[First@f@# , #] & /@ arg]) // Timing
```

> {2.012413, 4.53175*10^6}

This finding the minimum Norm of the angles.. so will fail in cases where the min distance is across the date line, etc.

( You can supply `GeoDistance` as a `DistanceFunction` to `Nearest` but its very slow..)